# Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 wakes up spontaneously after sleeping

Tags: linux, rhel, thinkpad, sleep

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad T430 running Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.5. Today I put my computer to sleep, double checked 10 seconds later, only to find out after arriving to my office that my computer woke up inside my backpack. If ThinkPads weren't made of adamantium it would be probably fried. What's happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was fixed on the Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.6 release. The reason was because Symantec Endpoint Security (my company-issued antivirus) didn't seem to play well with Red Hat 6.5's suspension/hibernation features. The next distro release fixed this issue and after upgrading I haven't had any spontaneous wake-ups.

Answer (score 0):

This used to happen to me when I was running Fedora 14 on my Thinkpad T410. I never was able to determine why it was happening, and would just make doubly sure that my laptop was actually suspended prior to putting it in my laptop bag.

Since migrating to Fedora 19 that particular problem has no longer occurred.

Answer (score 0):

The bios has wake on-lan enabled even if disconnected.  I have the same laptop and was able to fix it by turning off the wake on lan feature in the bios.